# How to lable URLs acording to Start URLs in APIFY

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer, apify

Using `Web Scraper`  you can input multiple `Start URLs`.
You can label them using `Glob Patterns` or `Pseudo-URLs`.

I have multiple URLs to crawl, but they can't be distinct using `Glob Patterns` or `Pseudo-URLs`.

The only option I was thinking of is to split it into multiple tasks.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I understand your question. For both StartURLs and Glob Patterns/PseudoURLs, you can click Advanced and provide some User Data (any JSON data) - this data is then available in the Page function as `context.request.userData` (context being the first argument of the function). Does that suit your needs? If not, please clarify your question so I can help you better.

Comment: Hi, I can't use Glob Patterns or Pseudo-URLs, because URLs don't have any distinct format. Let's say I have 2 menu links, Mens, and womens. So I want to know wich page was crawled from which menu link. But scrapped URLs don't have men\women mentioned in. Is that more clear?

Comment: So you aren't concerned about the start urls, but your flow is that you have some start url, where you scrape the menu, and from there you get urls for the next pages, which you want to distinguish? In that case, you can't use the selector field in the actor input directly, but you need to encode this logic in the page function and use `context.enqueueRequest()` - I'll write a full answer if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Hi @M.Volf, any chance you wite that answer you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a page with links that have the same selectors, but you want to distinguish them by the heading that they were under, using simply the selectors, globs and pseudoURLs is usually not enough, so you'll need to write your own logic in the page function.

Let's take an example of [docs.apify.com](https://docs.apify.com) as a page where you might want to do that:

[image: Screenshot of Apify documentation homepage]

Now let's say you want to scrape the links under Guides and Platform features, but using different handlers. To do that, you have to go through the section boxes one by one, for each check the title, and then eventually enqueue the links. This code in the pageFunction should work:

```js
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { label } = context.request.userData;
    if (label === "GUIDES") {
        context.log.info(`Handling guide link: ${context.request.url}`);
        // ...
        return;
    }
    if (label === "PLATFORM") {
        context.log.info(`Handling platform feature link: ${context.request.url}`);
        // ...
        return;
    }

    const $ = context.jQuery;
    for (const cardElement of $("[data-test=MenuCard]").toArray()) {
        const title = $("h2", cardElement).text().trim();
        let label;
        if (title.toLowerCase() === "guides") {
            label = "GUIDES"
        } else if (title.toLowerCase() === "platform features") {
            label = "PLATFORM"
        }
        if (label !== undefined) {
            for (const link of $(".card-body-wrap li a", cardElement)) {
                await context.enqueueRequest({
                    url: new URL(link.href, context.request.loadedUrl).toString(),
                    userData: {
                        label,
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```